# crystal report as website

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, asp.net-2.0

Ok I am not sure the question I need to ask so I am going to describe what I would like to be able to do I am wondering if this is possible.

I have some paper forms that I am creating webpages for so that the information can be stored in the database using a computer. I have already created one and the user enters the information it is stored in the database then the user has the option to print a crystal report that looks like the paper form with the information entered.

Is it possible to cut out the middle man and have a crystal report as a webpage that the user can hit enter the information into the report and then hit a save control on the page to save it to the database and print from there.

If I am not asking the right question or you need more information please feel free to ask. If it is possible to design the report and then use that on the page make it editable to the client then that would make my life a whole lot easier I just dont know what to look up.

Comment: You want to use Crystal **Reports** as data entry? Not possible, they're for reporting only...

Comment: Thanks i figured that might be the case just hoped there was a possible solution.

Comment: It is possible (see below), but it's a *terrible* idea.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to let user fill out a form and the data can save to database, and then the user can access the form, then there are several options:

1. Use Adobe forms. In this way, you can create pdf forms and you can let people download or email the forms. The forms are fillable, and when they submit the form, all you need is handle it(in forms of xml) at your server side to save it to your database. You could pre-populate data so that when the user download the file and open it, it has some data filled out. The tool you will need to create Adobe forms is Adobe LiveCycle and you have to learn how to use it. Our company use it for some of our web forms because they are secure and can be emailed. Of course you will need to implement server side code to handle it.
2. Use asp.net web form. You create web form and linked to database. You handle the form data user entered and save them to the database by using ado.net. That give you the most flexibilities.

   If you want user open the form they entered in a specific format so that it will looks like a "form", you have two options:

   <1> Pass your raw data to a specific css to let user print out in a nicer format instead of just plain text or even the web page. Again, you get flexibilities through this way.

   <2> Use SQL Server Report Services(If you use sql server). In this way, you can create print layouts by using visual studio, and then write a stored procedure to get data. If you do this way, the user will also get a pdf file. They can save it or print it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (assuming you are using a version of SQL which allows you to write stored procedures), but it's a very bad idea:

1. Write a SQL stored procedure, with a parameter for each field to be entered, that updates the relevant database tables with the appropriate parameter values.
2. Generate a Crystal report from the stored procedure.

Note that the only functionality available to the data entry fields (lookups, validation, etc.) will be that available to Crystal Report parameters in whichever version of Crystal you are using - generally, this functionailty is minimal.